# I add an item to an array but when i ask for it, it returns "undefined". (React useState hook)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Simplified version of the code:

```
const [nums, setNums] = React.useState([5]);
const [result, setResult] = React.useState(0);

let op = "-"

let disp = "5";

if (op === '=') {
      setNums([...nums, Number.parseInt(disp)]);
      setResult(nums[1]) 
}
```

I clearly add a second number to the array using a React useState hook, and then use it to set the result, but result returns "undefined"

I should be able to set the result to "5", but instead it sets it to "undefined", console.log(nums) returns [5, 5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you provided, it seems that you are trying to set the second element of the `nums` array as the value of `result`. However, when you call `setNums([...nums, Number.parseInt(disp)])`, you are actually adding a new element to the `nums` array, not modifying the existing one.

Therefore, when you call `setResult(nums[1])`, `nums[1]` is `undefined`, since there is no second element in the nums array until you add it in the previous line. That's why `result` is also `undefined`.

To set `result` to the correct value, you need to use the updated `nums` array after adding the new element. Here's one way you could modify the code to achieve that:

```
const [nums, setNums] = React.useState([5]);
const [result, setResult] = React.useState(0);

let op = "-"

let disp = "5";

if (op === '=') {
    const newNums = [...nums, Number.parseInt(disp)]; // create a new array with the added element
    setNums(newNums);
    setResult(newNums[1]) // set result to the second element of the updated array
}
```

With this code, `result` should now be set to `5`, and `console.log(nums)` should return `[5, 5]`.